# Remove tab on product for one category, keep but change image for another

Tags: images, filters

On our WooCommerce WordPress product page, I was able to remove the 'Additional Information; tab with the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab

    return $tabs;

}
```

However we have an additional tab 'Sizing' we want this to show on one of our two main categories (show only on one category).

I have tried running the above along with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 99 );
function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    //get all categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'synthetic-wigs' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
    {
            $categories[synthetic-wigs] = $term-synthetic-wigs;
    }
    if ( in_array( 'synthetic-wigs', $categories ) ) {  
        unset( $tabs['sizing'] ); // (Sizing tab)  
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab) 
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

This didn't work and caused a critical error. How can I remove one tab from all and another tab from just one?

I have also been tasked with updating the image within the sizing tab but it looks like this is coded in the theme.

Is it possible to combine all 3 requests (remove additional info from all, remove sizing from one category, update sizing image) in one code snippet?

Page example: https://www.lacefronts.com.au/product/lace-front-human-hair-wig-light-blonde-bob-with-bangs-wig-6-inch-bron/

New image: https://www.lacefronts.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/Lace-Fronts-Australia-wig-size-chart.png